# Django Getting Only One String from List Instead of All

Tags: python, django, post, request

I have two lists in my request.POST that I'm trying to use in my code. They look like the following, and I confirmed their structure even by looking at Django's dump:

```
POST:<QueryDict: {u'rasters': [u'240p', u'720p'], u'title': [u'algies_2'], u'destination': [u'algies_2'], u'framerate': [u'60'], u'formats': [u'MP4', u'WEBM']
```

What I'm trying to do is the following in one of my views:

```
...
'-p 2', '-f', ",".join([format.lower() for format in request.POST['formats']]), '-t', ",".join(request.POST['rasters'])
...
```

However, what it's doing is not joining the 'rasters' and 'formats' lists as comma separated lists (i.e., '240p,720p' and 'mp4,webm') but instead just returning a comma-separated list of the characters of the last entry in each list (i.e., '7,2,0,p' and 'w,e,b,m'). I feel like I'm doing everything right here; am I missing some sort of subtle bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`POST` is a [`QueryDict`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#querydict-objects) object, which has special behavior when multiple values are submitted in the HTTP POST for the same key. To get all of them, use the [`getlist`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist) method. So your formating code would look like this:

```
",".join([format.lower() for format in request.POST.getlist('formats')])
```