# Unable to get all values from the GET dictionary in django

Tags: python, django, dictionary, get, request

I have a django view that gets data from `request.GET`

```
def get_values_from_GET(request):
    print request.GET, >>>>
    print request.get('ids[]', None)
    return redirect('hurray')
```

**Output**

```
<QueryDict: {u'ids[]': [u'15', u'14']}> >>>>
14 >>>>
```

So i can able to see the list of values in `request.GET`, but can see only one value when trying to access, so y this happening ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django Getting Only One String from List Instead of All](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19506316/django-getting-only-one-string-from-list-instead-of-all)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`QueryDict.getlist`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist):

```
request.GET.getlist('ids[]', None)
```